# Skin id mapping is getting issue is asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

It might be a basic question but difficult for me because i'm trying at first time.

I've defined skin (Button2.skin) in this structure App_Themes\Theme2\Button2.skin. Hence I added the below lines under the skin file

```
<asp:Button runat="server" SkinID="Button2"
  BackColor="Green" 
  ForeColor="White" 
  Font-Name="Arial" 
  Font-Size="19px" />
```

In my page I've defined the skinid for Label as like below even it was saying "The Skin ID value is not defined the theme or stylesheet theme"

```
<asp:Button ID="CompanyName" runat="server"  SkinID="Button2" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Something I was missing but I didn't know what was exactly? Please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out what was the issue. It's because of Theme attribute has been missed at current Page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Contoso Home Page" Theme="Theme2" Language="C#" />
```